# How to define custom URI scheme for windows executable generated with Install4J

Tags: install4j

We have generated a Installable for both Mac OS X and windows using Install4J. Install4J provides an option to provide custom xml fragments to be added to Info.plist of the application to register your custom URI scheme so that you open up an app by just typing customuri:// in the browser address bar. But couldn't find any option for Windows executable. Would really appreciate if someone can provide some light into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with registry entries, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx